# Can not use mail command

Tags: fedora, mail-command

error like this:

```
[user1@fedora ~]$ mail
No mail for user1
```

but that is appear Maildir(mailbox) in /home/user1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most versions of `mail` (there are several) do not support the Maildir format, only the older Mailbox format. Use a more sophisticated mail client such as [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/).

Comment: +1 mutt is great! Try `mutt -f /the/maildir/folder`
I used it at the time I was running my own email server solution. Advice: Try mutt on a dumb account before using it on a "real life email inbox".

Answer (score 0):

Send yourself an email

`demo_user@box:/> mail`

No mail for demo_user

`demo_user@box:/> mail -s "Test mail" demo_user@box`

Test

EOT

Note: once you hit enter after your mail address for user1@fedora
type something in and press `CTRL+D` (hold Control key and press D key)

```
demo_user@box:~> mail
Heirloom mailx version 12.2 01/07/07.  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/demo_user": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 demo_user@box Mon Mar 26 09:54   20/983   Test mail
?
```

One you send the email you should be able to enter your account. There might be a better way to do this but it will work. Also, if you don't have a mail file it will generate one.